# Executing a Javascript function from an asp.net codebehind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, code-behind

OK, this feels like a question that should be easy to answer, but as with so much mixing of asp.net and jQuery, it's a bit of a nightmare.

What I want to do is be fading a `div` in and out at various times during the client's viewing of my asp.net page; I fade it out using jQuery's `fadeTo()` before triggering an UpdatePanel update (to indicate that the data there is not fresh) and I want to fade it in again once the UpdatePanel has been updated.  I've gotten as far as updating the UpdatePanel in the codebehind, and this results in the `div`'s content changing... but how do I fade the `div` back in again?

The way I see it, there are 2 ways; register an event handler on page load to detect when the `div`'s content has been changed and fade it back in, or call a function from the asp.net codebehind when I've updated the `div` to fade it back in.

In the first case, there doesn't seem to be *any* event triggered by the `div`'s content changing, so I can't seem to do that.  If anyone knows how I could get a client event to trigger when I update the `div`, that would be a nice solution.

In the second case, I thought that this was what `ClientScriptManager` was for, but it doesn't quite do what I want.  I want to be able to register a particular Javascript function with `ClientScriptManager` and then tell `ClientScriptManager` to execute it in the client, from my codebehind.  You can't seem to do that.  `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` simply inserts some `<script>` into the HTML output, rather than calling a function.  Presumably this would work if I kept registering things like:

```
<script>fadeBackIn();</script>
```

because the Javascript would be immediately evaluated and run, but this feels messy, and that feeling is intensified by the fact that I'd have to keep randomly generating a new unique value for the `key` argument of `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`, because it's specifically designed to *stop* this kind of repeated code.  However, I'm struggling to see an alternative.  Can anyone come up with a good idea as to a better mechanism to get this to work?

I'd really like something along the lines of:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptFunction("fadeBackIn", "function fadeBackIn(){ ... }");

[...]

ClientScriptManager.ExecuteClientScriptFunction("fadeBackIn");
```

but I don't see that functionality available.  :-(

Comment: How do you expect ClientScriptManager to call client side code when it is being executed on the server?

Comment: Presumably, using the same kind of mechanism that allows a codebehind to dynamically update the contents of an UpdatePanel.  A framework that allows AJAX communication between the client and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the page loaded event. The pageLoaded handler recieves an argument of type PageLoadedEventArgs which contains a get_panelsUpdated method that you can call to enumerate all the UpdatePanels whose content was just updated.

Example:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded(sender, args) 
{
    var panels = args.get_panelsUpdated();

    if (panels.length > 0) 
    {
        for (var i in panels) 
        {
            if (panels[i].id == "DesiredUpdatePanelId") 
            {
                fadeBackIn(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because html is stateless, you'll need an asynchronous way of determining if the content has changed in your div. I would try using the window.setInterval to check if your content has changed every 500ms or so.

If your div looks like this:

```
<div id="mycontent">Blah, blah.</div>
```

Then this might be a solution:

```
$(function(){

   var $mycontent = $('#mycontent');
   var myContentHtml = $mycontent.html();
   var intervalId;

   function checkIfDivChanged()
   {
      window.clearInterval(intervalId);

      if (myContentHtml != $mycontent.html())
      {
         myContentHtml = $mycontent.html();

         // run update here..
         fadeBackIn();

         // if you want to stop the check then uncomment next line..
         // return;
      }

      intervalId = window.setInterval(checkIfDivChanged, 500);          
   }

   checkIfDivChanged();
});
```

Comment: I don't see what state has to do with this.  This is about detecting an event.

Comment: If you're looking for a client side event, then you would need to put your content in a <select>, <input>, or <textarea> tag. Then, with jquery, you could bind to the change event. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I tried doing precisely that; I created an `<input>` textbox and changed its contents in the codebehind, but no event got triggered.  Any ideas why?  Could you provide a code example?

Comment: Without looking at your code, I'm not sure how you could fire a client javascript change event from the code behind, since changing the input value occurs before the browser receives the html. In order for the javascript change event to occur, the value of the input would need to be changed after the page has loaded. Does that help or make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, or are willing to use the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit, it contains a control that does exactly what you are looking for: UpdatePanelAnimation.

Take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx) for more information on that control, and [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/UsingAnimations.aspx) for more information on using animations.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using that monstrosity in favour of jQuery.  :-)

Comment: That's fair enough. I don't blame you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written small script with pure JavaScript (no jQuery required), you can just have this script in your page and change the alert part.. plus of course the ID of the div element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _watchTimer = 0;
window.onload = function WindowLoad(evt) {
    _watchTimer = window.setInterval("WatchForChange();", 100);
}

function WatchForChange()
{
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("MyDivToWatch");
    if (oDiv == null)
    {
        window.clearInterval(_watchTimer);
        return;
    }
    var prevHtml = oDiv.getAttribute("prev_html") || "";
    var curHtml = oDiv.innerHTML;
    if (prevHtml != curHtml)
    {
        if (prevHtml.length > 0)
        {
            alert("content changed");
        }
        else
        {
            //first run, ignore
        }
        oDiv.setAttribute("prev_html", curHtml);
    }
}
</script>
<div id="MyDivToWatch">I can be changed..</div>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('MyDivToWatch').innerHTML += ' like this..';">Change</button>
```

Added the whole code used to test, used a button to dynamically change the contents but it should work with changing it via AJAX call aka UpdatePanel.

Comment: Unfortunately this relies on a timer ticking away in the background which feels like a messy solution; I'd rather have an event based solution or the codebehind somehow triggering a Javascript function if possible.

Comment: Changing element contents raise no event (apart of form elements but it's not relevant in your case) so "event based solution" is dead end.. server don't have live connection with the client, it's "request/response oriented" so codebehind triggering JS function is dead end as well. Nothing messy with timer ticking, jQuery also have it behind the scenes.

Comment: Why is the form elements thing not relevant here?  I could get the codebehind to change form element contents, couldn't I?

Comment: Relevant, but dead end because there's no event raised. Glad you have it solved now, that's the beauty of so many experts in one place.. most of the times one of them will have the answer. :)